# Allow - (dash) but no leading zero in HTML input field

Tags: html, reactjs, validation, input, jsx

Is there any way to allow - (dash) in front of number in an HTML input field like -110 but no leading zero like 0111 etc. So, the idea behind all of this to allow me use -110 as a negative number in my calculation.
Currently my input field looks like this:

```
<input type="number" value={amount} onChange={(e) => setAmount(e.target.value)} placeholder="$" 
/>
```

I have tried many different things but nothing quite worked for me. Any help?

Comment: unclear what is your issue with negative number in an input. What validation did you use that had the issue?

Comment: I want to be able to enter two types of user input in the input field. Like, first one -1234 and I don't want leading zero.